# Javascript: message by login

Tags: javascript, message

i have this chatbox, and when users login i want it to send a message like this:

> Admin: User is online

I really want to use a javascript code for this, because i can work with it quite good. I already have some example, but the problem here is that it does not do something until it is called to do it's function. THATS what i want to achieve, just that when the page is opened up, it does that function one time.

```
function onLine(message)
{
document.writeform.bericht.value+=message;
document.writeform.bericht.focus();
write1();
}
```

explanation: onLine is the function and (message) tells what it should say. For example:

```
...
onclick="onLine('User is online');"
...
```

the function write1() sends it.

HELP?!

Comment: What exactly is your question? I do not understand.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: i want basiclly that the function is called when the page opens. see the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to run that function once when the page is loaded? If so, you have many possible ways to do it. A couple of simple ones:

```
<body onload="onLine('User is online')">
```

This will call the function when all the page components are loaded. You could also add this to the end of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  onLine('User is online');
</script>
```

There are also javascript libraries like jQuery and prototype, which you should have a look at if you haven't yet.